# Getting groups subgroups and users from AD (quality check

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm retrieving all groups, subgroups, and users

I'm using the following code

```
ResultPropertyValueCollection resultCollection = result.Properties["member"];
                foreach (var oneResult in resultCollection)
                {

                    if (oneResult.ToString().IndexOf("OU=Groups") > -1)
                    {
                        group.SubGroupsNames.Add(GetCN(oneResult.ToString()));
                    }
                    else if (oneResult.ToString().IndexOf("OU=Users") > -1)
                    {
                        group.UsersNames.Add(GetCN(oneResult.ToString()));
                    }
                }
private string GetCN(string line)
    {
        return line.Substring(line.IndexOf("CN=") + 3, line.IndexOf(",") - line.IndexOf("=")-1);
    }
```

It works fine but as I will be controlled by Code quality controller, is there is a better way to write that? Or is it OK for you?

Answer (score 2):

I am not totally clear on what you are trying to do but I see some wheel reinventing going on here.

Take a look at `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`, particularly the `GroupPrincipal` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal.aspx).

You will find some great methods there such as `getMembers()` (with recursion), `IsMemberOf()` and plenty of other useful stuff.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement' is very slow since i'm getting a huge number of records that's why i switch to 'DirectoryService' my main question is about the code style especially the if else statement and if there is better way to do that maybe Ldap query ? thanks again